# require_once() function unable to include functions()

Tags: php, function, include, absolute-path, document-root

index.php

```
<?php
require_once('fr.php');
header('Location:'.abspath().directory());
?>
```

fr.php

```
<?php
require_once('functions.php');
?>
```

functions.php

```
function abspath()
{
return $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
}
```

Now when i go to index.php, it gives me this error:-

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function abspath() in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 3
```

Comment: This looks okay. Are you 1000% sure all the files are correct and up to date?

Comment: Is your `fr.php` next to `index.php` in the folder structure?

Comment: your require is relative to the document. is the functions.php in the same place as index.php and fr.php?

Comment: this function is not in this .php you try to inlcude. or you order of include is not ok. First you must include it then you can use it.

Comment: I am using dreamweaver and can see that all files are properly linked...

Comment: The scripts posted for index.php and fr.php contain the `<?php` marker, the script for functions.php doesn't. Did you forget it just here or is it missing in the file on your server, too?

Comment: @VolkerK Good catch but I'd hope that would be painfully obvious to OP as it would dump the contents of functions.php to the screen before the error message

Comment: functions.php is still a php file, so add at least the opening <?php tag

Comment: I understand that this is not the question.. but you are redirecting to a path and not to an url

Comment: @VolkerK no actually its there in my functions file i have not written it here

Comment: @mishu m unable to get you :(

Comment: @AbhilashShukla if you found the problem then you can ignore me :) what I was referring to is the fact that $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] usually is a **path** (see here http://de.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) if you don't change the value.. and setting the location header is a way to redirect to an **url**; notice path vs. url (eg: C:\xampp\htdocs\ vs http:/ /localhost)

Comment: @mishu Actually things resolved but what you said is a great insight.... and definitely i might have come with this problem next day... thanks for the help and support :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey all my commenting people were right... i don't know why it happened but when i restarted my xampp it worked fine for me :)

So this is 100% correct

index.php

```
<?php
require_once('fr.php');
header('Location:'.abspath().directory());
?>
```

fr.php

```
<?php
require_once('functions.php');
?>
```

functions.php

```
function abspath()
{
return $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
}
```